# How do you change the size of a single cell in a collectionview? I want to take the value of a slider and use that value to resize the cell

Tags: ios, swift

So far I've created a collectionview with a label in each cell. I have a button that appends a new cell to an array. I can even get the cells to all change height equally based on a slider's value. However, I am not sure how to go about changing the size of only one single cell in the collection view. Anyone have insight on how to do this? I haven't seen an answer on it.

I can post my code if necessary

EDIT: since requested, here is the code:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return visualArray.count
}


func collectionView(_: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: self.collectionThing.frame.height / 6 * 5, height: CGFloat(sliderSlider.value * 4))
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VisualCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! VisualCollectionViewCell

    cell.visualLabel.text = visualArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: It is a good idea to post your code, as it helps people get the answer much quicker.

Comment: I posted the code!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using a `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`, the default layout, you can use the delegate method `func collectionView(UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: IndexPath) -> CGSize` to return a new size for that specific cell.

I believe you can trigger an animated re-layout if you call `collectionView.performBatchUpdates` with empty closures, you should do this once the size of the cell has changed.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to create a custom collection view layout, there are a few tutorials online about how to do that.